# map inside map in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

suppose i have this response

```
[
  {
    "userId": "5e5a0be699e0e4449829c444",
    "stepId": ["5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d", "5e5906dfc749dc4498033f7e"],
    "stepCount": 1,
    "stepode": "ST01"
  },
  {
    "userId": "5e5a0be699e0e4449829c444",
    "mappedToDealers": ["5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d", "5e5906dfc749dc4498033f7e"],
    "stepCount": 40,
    "stepode": "BD01"
  }
];
```

i am trying to push this into a new Object such that i can get single objects according stepId i.e

```
[
  {
    "userId": "5e5a0be699e0e4449829c444",
    "stepId": "5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d",
    "stepCount": 1,
    "stepode": "ST01"
  },
  {
    "userId": "5e5a0be699e0e4449829c444",
    "stepId": "5e5906dfc749dc4498033f7e",
    "stepCount": 1,
    "stepode": "ST01"
  },
  {
    "userId": "5e5a0be699e0e4449829c444",
    "stepId": "5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d",
    "stepCount": 40,
    "stepode": "BD01"
  },
  {
    "userId": "5e5a0be699e0e4449829c444",
    "mappedToDealers": "5e5906dfc749dc4498033f7e",
    "stepCount": 40,
    "stepode": "BD01"
  }
];
```

i think .map or forEach twice one inside the other but i have not been able to get this desired result.

Comment: you can use `Spread syntax` to merge these arrays: `[...arr1, ...arrr2]`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#A_better_way_to_concatenate_arrays

Comment: @ – zb22 yest but when i apply it with mappedToDealers it is returning an empty object

Answer (score 0):

How about `reduce` and `forEach`?

**data** = response

```
data.reduce((res, obj) => {
  obj.stepId.forEach(stepId => {
    res.push({
      ...obj,
      stepId
    });
  });
  return res;
}, []);
```

We create a new array and fill it with objects.